# Regex integer check

Tags: regex

I am using below validation expression to check for number range between 0-100. I would like to extend the check to also allow for exception of 999 (default value).

```
   reMatch(value,"^[0-9][0-9]?$|^100$")
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is `00` or `05` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
   reMatch(value,"^[0-9][0-9]?$|^100$|^999$")
```

Comment: No need to repeat the anchors so many times `^([0-9][0-9]?|100|999)$`

Answer (score 1):

Better use this:
`^[0-9][0-9]?$|^(100|999)$`